# How create correct has_one: :through Association for Audit model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

So I have a model for creating a Сhecklist that has ability to **dynamically add questions**.
I need to create another model in which I can store the answer to this question(Audit) but still link the answer to Audit.

When I click to button create I have an error:
`unknown attribute 'checklist_id' for Audit.`

Audit model:

```rb
class Audit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :checklists
  has_one :answers, through: :questions
end
```

Checklist model:

```rb
class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Question model

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :checklist

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 12..40 }
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Answer model

```rb
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  validates :answer, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
end
```

Routes (Not sure if this is right)

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'checklists#index'
  
  resources :checklists do
    resources :questions, only: [:create] do
      resources :answers, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end

  resources :checklists do
    resources :audits
  end
  
  resources :audits, only: [:index]
end
```

Form to create a new Audit audits/new.html.erb

```rb
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s8 offset-s2">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h5> <%= @checklist.title %></h5>
        <p> <%= @checklist.description %></p>
        <hr />
        <% @checklist.questions.any?  do %>
        <ul class="card-body">
          <span class="card-title">Answer <%= @checklist.cout_questions %> Questions:</span>
          <%= render @checklist.questions %>
        </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="card-action">
        <%= button_to 'Create', {controller: "audits", action: "create", checklists_id: @checklist.id}, method: :post, class: 'waves-effect waves-light btn' %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', checklists_path, class: 'waves-effect waves-light btn red darken-1'%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your associations are off. When using belongs_to and has_one the name should be singular. You're also declaring a ’through: questions’ association but there is no questions association in the model. The error message itself is telling you that the foreign key column is missing.

Comment: Its hard to tell what you are trying to do here and why you don't just add a answer_id column to audits to link it directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @max, didn't think about it. Yes, I can just store the  answer ID, but at the same time,  probably I have to write a service that will check the number of answers and not allow to create a new audit without filling in all the answers fields.